# RFID: What PowerBurst times should be used to communicate between the TMS3705 RFid transponder base station IC and the TMS37157 RFid device?

Tags: c, rfid

These PowerBurst times are used in the sample code referenced in the [TMS37157 Development Tool FAQ](http://focus.ti.com/lit/ml/swra309a/swra309a.pdf), but there seems to be no clue as to what these values are. It looks like they are provided by the desktop app, but I only have the binary for that.

```
struct stLFpacket               
{
    unsigned short usPowerBurst[4];
    ...
struct stLFpacket aLFpacket;
...
void DoPowerBurst(char number)
{
    if ((command1.field.PPM_PWM == 1) && (number == 2))
        SetOutput(&P1OUT, P1_TXCT, HIGH, BLCtimes.usToff, USEC, HALT);      
    SetOutput(&P1OUT, P1_TXCT, LOW, aLFpacket.usPowerBurst[number-1], MSEC, 
        HALT);
}
...
void GetPowerBurst(char number, char* Index)
{
    if (command1.field.TwoPB_OnePB == ONE_BYTE)
            aLFpacket.usPowerBurst[number-1] = USB_Buffer.ucData[*Index];
    else
            aLFpacket.usPowerBurst[number-1] = 16 * USB_Buffer.ucData[*Index] 
                + USB_Buffer.ucData[(*Index)+1];
    *Index++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to support@ti.com,

> The power burst times used for
>   TMS37157 should be 15-50ms for PB1 and
>   50ms for PB2.  In the base station
>   source code, dopowerburst(2),
>   dopowerburst(3), dopowerburst(4)
>   appear to be used for wake patterns in
>   some of our other automotive
>   transponders that operate a little
>   different from TMS37157.